# How can you load a PHP variable into a action Form post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my syntax.  I am trying to load a PHP value with the url Post.

Is there a way to post `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` and have it load into a div without using jquery or java?  That is what I would like to do more, but if you can only put a php variable into the post, that'll work too.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action = "answer_audit.php?action=search&auditID=<?php $auditID ?>"  name="audit_search_form" id="audit_search_form"  >
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="audit_comments" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="submitID" id="submit_search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you want yo past variable as GET parament via POST but nevertheless.There is no way of passing php var to html form except printout value of php var into place were html value should be. So you should do like this:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action = "answer_audit.php?action=search&auditID=<?php echo $auditID ?>"  name="audit_search_form" id="audit_search_form"  >
```

or

```
<form role="form" method="post" action = "answer_audit.php?action=search&auditID=<?= $auditID ?>"  name="audit_search_form" id="audit_search_form"  >
```

[**Link to documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> Is there a way to post  and have it load into a div
>   without using jquery or java?
>   Same, you can print any php valiable in any html place you want.

```
<div><?=$_PHP_SELF?></div>
```

or

```
<div><?php echo $_PHP_SELF?></div>
```

And about post, no, html post submit is  client side event and `php` is  server side engine. But there is a way to create post complitly on php  using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

here is small example:

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your PHP code is getting the `$auditID` variable but not actually doing anything with it. You need to echo it to the page. Either `<?php echo $auditID ?>` or `<?= $auditID ?>` will work, assuming your server supports the latter.

> Is there a way to post  and have it load into a div without using jquery or java?

Presumably you mean Javascript, not Java, but no there isn't. You would need to make an AJAX request to load content from PHP in to the page without reloading.